# How to print part of a tensor using tf.Print?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, when a tensor has large dimensions, it is useful to only print some part of the tensor for debugging purposes, such as the diagonal of a 2-d matrix. I only know how to print the entire tensor as follows:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000, 1000])
a = tf.Print(a, [a], "print entire a\n", summarize=1000000)
b = a + 1.
ret = sess.run(b)
```

The above code will print the entire 'a' tensor. But I'm not sure how to print part of 'a'. For example, if I only want to print a[0,0] without doing sess.run(a), the following code won't work:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000, 1000])
a[0,0] = tf.Print(a[0,0], [a[0,0]], "print part of a\n", summarize=1000000)
b = a + 1.
ret = sess.run(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> ```
> Print(
>     input_,
>     data,
>     message=None,
>     first_n=None,
>     summarize=None,
>     name=None
> )
> ```
>
> Prints a list of tensors. This is an identity op with the side effect
>   of printing `data` when evaluating.

`a` should remain the same, and in the `data` parameter you should place the tensor that you need to print.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000, 1000])
a = tf.Print(a, [a[0, 0]], "Print part of a\n", summarize=100000)
b = a + 1.
ret = sess.run(b)
```

Comment: Nice! A follow-up question: is there a way to print a formatted tensor? If you do a = tf.Print(a, [a[0:3, 0:3]]) for example, TF'd print [[1 1 1][1 1 1][1 1 1]] to console, instead of [[1 1 1] on one row, [1 1 1] on the next, etc.

Comment: Not with `tf.Print`, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sometimes is best just to have something like this `ret, avalue = sess.run([b, a]) `

Comment: My follow-up question is to see if there is an option to make the tf.Print results easy to read. Right now it only prints everything on 1 line, which could still be hard to read sometimes.

Comment: For me is easier to get the `avalue` after the `sess.run` and print it with a custom format. Another alternative is to use [`Summaries`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary) and/or tensorboard

Comment: Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bownM3L5zM) on how to use tensorboard, a bit silly but to the point